# trying to render an equirectangular panorama

Tags: c#, image-processing, panoramas

I have an equirectangular panorama source image which is 360 degrees of longitude and 120 degrees of latitude.

I want to write a function which can render this, given width and height of the viewport and a rotation in longitude. I want to can my output image so that it's the full 120 degrees in height.

has anyone got any pointers? I can't get my head around the maths on how to transform from target coordinates back to source.

thanks

slip

Here is my code so far:- (create a c# 2.0 console app, add a ref to system.drawing)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Bitmap src = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\jon\slippyr4\pt\grid2.jpg");

        // constant stuff
        double view_width_angle = d2r(150);
        double view_height_angle = d2r(120);
        double rads_per_pixel = 2.0 * Math.PI / src.Width;

        // scale everything off the height
        int output_image_height = src.Width;

        // compute radius (from chord trig - my output image forms a chord of a circle with angle view_height_angle)
        double radius = output_image_height / (2.0 * Math.Sin(view_height_angle / 2.0));

        // work out the image width with that radius.
        int output_image_width = (int)(radius * 2.0 * Math.Sin(view_width_angle / 2.0));

        // source centres for later
        int source_centre_x = src.Width / 2;
        int source_centre_y = src.Height / 2;

        // work out adjacent length
        double adj = radius * Math.Cos(view_width_angle / 2.0);

        // create output bmp
        Bitmap dst = new Bitmap(output_image_width, output_image_height);

        // x & y are output pixels offset from output centre
        for (int x = output_image_width / -2; x < output_image_width / 2; x++)
        {
            // map this x to an angle & then a pixel
            double x_angle = Math.Atan(x / adj);
            double src_x = (x_angle / rads_per_pixel) + source_centre_x;

            // work out the hypotenuse of that triangle
            double x_hyp = adj / Math.Cos(x_angle);

            for (int y = output_image_height / -2; y < output_image_height / 2; y++)
            {
                // compute the y angle and then it's pixel
                double y_angle = Math.Atan(y / x_hyp);
                double src_y = (y_angle / rads_per_pixel) + source_centre_y;

                Color c = Color.Magenta;
                // this handles out of range source pixels. these will end up magenta in the target
                if (src_x >= 0 && src_x < src.Width && src_y >= 0 && src_y < src.Height)
                {
                    c = src.GetPixel((int)src_x, (int)src_y);
                }


                dst.SetPixel(x + (output_image_width / 2), y + (output_image_height / 2), c);
            }
        }

        dst.Save(@"C:\Users\slippyr4\Desktop\pana.jpg");

    }

    static double d2r(double degrees)
    {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
    }
```

[image: source image i am using]

With this code, i get the results i expect when i set my target image width to 120 degrees. I see the right curvature of horizontal lines etc, as below, and when i try it with a real-life equirectangular panorama, it looks like commercial viewers render.
[image: correct output at 120 degrees by 120 degrees]

But, when i make the output image wider, it all goes wrong. You start to see the invalid pixels in a parabola top and bottom at the centre, as shown here with the image 150 degrees wide by 120 degrees high:-

[image]

What commericial viewers seem to do is sort of zoom in - so the in the centre, the image is 120 degrees high and therefore at the sides, more is clipped. and therfore, there is no magenta (ie, no invalid source pixels).

But i can't get my head around how to do that in the maths.

This isn't homework, it's a hobby project. hence why i am lacking the understanding of what is going on!. Also, please forgive the severe inefficeincy of the code, i will optimise it when i have it working propertly.

thanks again

Comment: can you please give your code or is it homework for us...?

Comment: i've added code and sample images now. it's not homework, i just was rather hoping for some pointers to articles that might help me figure out the correct math, rather than having someone hand me the solution... hence not posting all my work. i'm actually having a tough time finding out much about this despite a lot of googling - i guess i'm not searching for the right things.